# Add column in oracle of Datatype which will be derived form Datatype of Column of another table

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have ran into a unique problem where,

I don't want to specify the datatype while creating a new column using alter statement.

```
alter table <TABLE_NAME> add <COLUMN_NAME> <DATATYPE> constraint TABLE2_FK references TABLE2(C2);
```

Here in this scenario I don't want to specify my Datatype as integer. Instead I want to do something like this. So that it picks up automatically the datatype of the other column.

```
'%TYPE SYS.TABLE2.ID'
```

Is this possible?

If not what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Do **NOT** create tables in the `SYS` user.

Comment: I would ask, "WHY"?  You know the data type of the column you want to reference, so why not just specify it in the first place instead trying to jump thorough these convoluted hoops?  What _real problem_ would this solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PL/SQL to create the DDL statement:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_src_table  VARCHAR2(30) := 'TABLE2';
  v_src_column VARCHAR2(30) := 'ID';
  v_dst_table  VARCHAR2(30) := 'TABLE1';
  v_dst_column VARCHAR2(30) := 'T2_ID';
  v_dst_constr VARCHAR2(30) := v_dst_table || '_' || v_dst_column || '_FK';
  v_type       VARCHAR2(30);
  v_precision  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_scale      PLS_INTEGER;
  v_sql_prefix VARCHAR2(100) := 'ALTER TABLE "' || v_dst_table || '" ADD "' || v_dst_column || '" ';
  v_sql_suffix VARCHAR2(100) := ' CONSTRAINT "' || v_dst_constr || '" REFERENCES "' || v_src_table || '" ( "' || v_src_column || '" )';
  v_sql        VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  SELECT DATA_TYPE,
         DECODE(
           DATA_TYPE,
           'VARCHAR2',  DATA_LENGTH,
           'CHAR',      DATA_LENGTH,
           'NVARCHAR2', DATA_LENGTH,
           'NCHAR',     DATA_LENGTH,
                        DATA_PRECISION
         ),
         DECODE(
           DATA_TYPE,
           'VARCHAR2',  NULL,
           'CHAR',      NULL,
           'NVARCHAR2', NULL,
           'NCHAR',     NULL,
                        DATA_SCALE
         )
  INTO   v_type,
         v_precision,
         v_scale
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  table_name  = v_src_table
  AND    column_name = v_src_column;
  
  IF v_precision IS NULL THEN
    v_sql := v_sql_prefix || v_type || v_sql_suffix;
  ELSIF v_scale IS NULL THEN
    v_sql := v_sql_prefix || v_type || '(' || v_precision || ')' || v_sql_suffix;
  ELSE
    v_sql := v_sql_prefix || v_type || '(' || v_precision || ',' || v_scale || ')' || v_sql_suffix;
  END IF;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_sql );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 ( id NUMBER(8,-4) PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE table1( id NUMBER(8,0) );
```

Executes the statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "TABLE1" ADD "T2_ID" NUMBER(8,-4) CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_T2_ID_FK" REFERENCES "TABLE2" ( "ID" )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2a970dd3d77c41cadb0a9767749b177)*

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, not possible.

But, if it suits your needs, create a **view** instead - it'll "inherit" column's datatype.